# Hair Particle System Not Showing Up In Render

Tags: rendering, particles, hair, settings

[image]

[image]

I am running into an issue where my hair particle system doesn't appear in the render. I have previous iterations that would produce the hair in the render so I am stuck on what settings I could have changed to result in the hair particle not showing up. The image on the left is what I see in the viewport and the image on the right is the rendered result. I have made sure the

I am using blender 3.4

Comment: You find how to fix this?
I have the same problem